# Dynamic linking libgit2 .so in gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, dynamic-linking, libgit2

I'm running a Debian (Buster) container and my goal is to compile a small program I wrote which relies on `libgit2`. First, I was installing `libgit2` via the [libgit2-dev](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libgit2-dev) package and my `Makefile` had the following:

```
gcc -O2 -fpic -shared -I /usr/local/include -lgit2 -o output.so my_app.c
```

However, I'd rather have a "cleaner" environment and install `libgit2` via the [libgit-27](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libgit2-27) which, AFAIK, only installs the shared object binary instead of also including the development files like `libgit2-dev` does.

Using `find` I can find where the `.so` file is installed into:

```
$ find / -name "*git2*" -print 2>/dev/null
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgit2.so.0.27.7
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgit2.so.27
/usr/share/doc/libgit2-27
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgit2-27:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgit2-27:amd64.symbols
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgit2-27:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgit2-27:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgit2-27:amd64.triggers
```

and I've been trying several combinations of linking this `.so` with `gcc` like:

```
gcc -O2 -fpic -shared -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -libgit2.so.27 -o output.so my_app.c
```

but so far I always get the following error:

```
my_app.c:1:10: fatal error: git2.h: No such file or directory
 #include <git2.h>
          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I understand this is a glaring lack of knowledge on how C compilation works. My two questions are:

1. Is it possible to compile my program by just relying on the `libgit2-27` Debian Buster package instead of `libgit2-dev`? If not, why?
2. If yes, an example and explanation would be appreciated!

Comment: In your 2nd attempt (that combines compile and link steps, and fails at 1st one) you are missing `-I /usr/local/include`. As for specifying the *.lib*, there are multiple ways, you could try `-l/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgit2.so.27` (full path) for example.

Comment: @CristiFati I appreciate your comment, but it didn't solve my issue. I tried with both the `-l` and `-L` flags